# How can I split a big string, which contains repeating text inside it into substrings

Tags: php

How can I split a big string, which contains repeating text inside it into substrings.

I have a big string ($all) which has this text repeated:

```
<span class="span7 listing freeListing"
```

I want to break this string $all into substrings stored in an array.
How can I do this with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I get your question, but if you want to use that substring as a separator, then

```
explode('<span class="span7 listing freeListing"', $all)
```

is what you are looking for. This will return an `array` of the substrings except the separator. However, I am not sure I understood your question, since you did not specify what you are expecting exactly.

Comment: I was glad to help, friend.